# Weird behavior of calling docker run from bash script

Tags: bash, docker

I try to run docker run from bash script and docker says:
“is not a docker command”
If I print the docker command line before I called docker and I copy it to clipboard and paste it to command line it works well!

here is the command in bash script:

```
local args="run ${nw_param} ${opts} --name ${img} ${repository}/${img}:${tag}"
docker ${args}
```

the current echo of args string is:

```
run --net=ehvb-network -d --restart=always --name my-module my-private-registry:5000/my-module:0.0.1-1555334810
```

When I copied this string to the clipboard and paste it to command line it works well.
I use Debian stretch. My script is using bash (#!/bin/bash)

When I remove ${opts} it runs from bash. Opts currently contains “-d --restart=always”. When I try to use only -d or only --restart=always it works well. But when I try to use both together it doesn’t work well.
And I try to define opts like this:

```
opts=’–restart=always -d’
```

the message from docker is:
    docker: Error response from daemon: invalid restart policy ‘always -d’, but the print message contains:
    opts:–restart=always -d

Somebody removes --restart=

Comment: Hm, I'm struggling to reproduce this. As you're using `local`, I assume you run this in a function. Could you provide the code for this one?

Comment: Note that using `$opts` is bad form in general; lists of options should be stored in arrays, not strings, to avoid a variety of subtle bugs. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050): *I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but complex cases always fail!*

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that, I used variables coming from other bash command in my script (like curl, ps etc). All of these variables end with carriage return \r. When I try to insert these variables into a docker parameter string \r are inside it. I need to add:
| sed 's/\r//' to all of these commands.

Comment: This isn't true on most operating systems -- UNIX newlines are just `\n`, not `\r\n`; the latter is a Windows-ism.